# How to completely uninstall Flash Player in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, uninstall, flash

This question is NOT about uninstalling the [standalone Flash Player](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

As a Windows user, I almost never use Adobe Flash Player. But is it possible to...

- Uninstall the built-in Flash Player in [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
- Uninstall the built-in Flash Player in [Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/microsoft-edge)
- Uninstall the built-in Flash Player in Windows ([Flash updates when Windows updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b6Qu.png))

...so that Flash won't be remained and updated?

Comment: It is built into Edge and I am fairly sure you cannot remove it.  When Edge becomes Chromium-based and early next year, I think, Flash will be removed.

Comment: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-adobe-flash-player-from-windows-10